# Will TransformBlock<TInput,TOutput>.TryReceiveAll(IList<TOutput>) return true when if and only if all the element(s) received?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

[image: Screenshot from the documentation of TryReceiveAll method]

Previously pasted picture is the official definition. But I am still confused. Does it return true if and only if all the element(s) received?

Comment: The title of the question is a bit confusing, around the words *"when if and only if"*. Honestly I can't tell what you want to know exactly. Could you edit the question and remove the ambiguity from the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the documentation

[`TransformBlock<TInput,TOutput>.TryReceiveAll(IList<TOutput>) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2.tryreceiveall?view=net-5.0)

> **Returns**
>
> `true` if **one or more** items could be received; otherwise, `false`.

It says it *returns* `true` if it has received **at least** 1 *item*

Let's make sure:

```
...

while (_messages.TryDequeue(out item)) 
    tmpList.Add(item);

countReceived = tmpList.Count;

...

if (countReceived > 0)
{
    // Notify the owner block that our count has decreased
    if (_itemsRemovedAction != null)
    {
        int count = _itemCountingFunc != null ? _itemCountingFunc(_owningSource, default(TOutput)!, items) : countReceived;
        _itemsRemovedAction(_owningSource, count);
    }
    return true;
}
else return false;
```

Yup, documentation is correct...

> Does it return true if and only if all the element(s) received?

I guess the answer to this revolves around what you class as ***all***...

What is buffered internally awaiting dispatch (queued), and what is in your pipeline may be 2 completely different things. `TryReceiveAll` will only return queued items. Items that haven't been queued (ergo not available) or otherwise held-up in other blocks (which you may consider **all**) is not classed as received.

For instance, you could have 10 items in flight in your entire pipeline, only 2 has hit the transform block and awaiting dispatch. `TryReceiveAll` will return those 2 available items, and return true.

Comment: Thank you, How do I do, when I need waiting all the element(s) received, BTW, Microsoft need to rename TryReceiveAll to TryReceiveAny......

Comment: @Fuqin it depends on what you are doing, you can await `transformblock.Completion` after you have signaled `Complete` on either the transform block itself, or a highblock that has been configured to pass the completion status along

Comment: @Fuqin Sorry i just realised, `Completion` and `TryRecieveAll` is not going to do what you want, The TansformBlock will never meet the conditions to await completion. You will need to use `Complete` in conjunction with `OutputAvailableAsync`, Theodor Zoulias gives a good example of this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410007/1612975. All things being equal, pipelines should really pipe not block an dump

Answer (score -1):

After I digging some source code comments,
I found a clue to resolve this problem.
The stack overflow always lost the picture, so I pasted two source code comments
First:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Represents a dataflow block.
public interface IDataflowBlock
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets a Task that represents the asynchronous operation and completion of the
    //     dataflow block.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     A dataflow block is considered completed when it is not currently processing
    //     a message and **when it has guaranteed that it will not process any more messages.**
    //     The returned Task will transition to a completed state when the associated block
    //     has completed. It will transition to the RanToCompletion state when the block
    //     completes its processing successfully according to the dataflow block’s defined
    //     semantics, it will transition to the Faulted state when the dataflow block has
    //     completed processing prematurely due to an unhandled exception, and it will transition
    //     to the Canceled state when the dataflow block has completed processing prematurely
    //     due to receiving a cancellation request. If the task completes in the Faulted
    //     state, its Exception property will return an System.AggregateException containing

    //     the one or more exceptions that caused the block to fail.
    Task Completion { get; }
```

Second:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Attempts to synchronously receive an item from the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ISourceBlock`1.
//
// Parameters:
//   source:
//     The source from which to receive.
//
//   item:
//     The item received from the source.
//
// Returns:
//     true if an item could be received; otherwise, false.
//
// Remarks:
//     This method does not wait until the source has an item to provide. It will return
//     whether or not an element was available.
public static bool TryReceive<TOutput>(this IReceivableSourceBlock<TOutput> source, out TOutput item);
```

Hence, I think we can code this can receiveAllMessage

```
      block.Complete();
await block.Completion.Configuration(false);
block.TryReceiveAll(out items);
```