# Custom Dataflow transform block with dynamic MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I receive a sequence of objects (e.g., `ItemGroup[]`) that each contains multiple jobs (e.g., `Item[]`) and a max degree of parallelism value, for example:

```
public record Item(string Name);
public record ItemGroup(Item[] Items, int MaxDegreeOfParallelism);
```

The sequence of `ItemGroup` instances must be processed sequentially, but each `ItemGroup` may have a max degree of parallelism higher than 1. For example, the pipeline will process the group of `A*` items sequentially, then process the group of `B*` items concurrently:

```
var groups = new[]
{
    new ItemGroup(new[] { new Item("A0"), new Item("A1"), new Item("A2") }, 1),
    new ItemGroup(new[] { new Item("B0"), new Item("B1"), new Item("B2") }, 3)
};
```

I thought a custom `TransformManyBlock` implementation derived from `IPropagatorBlock<ItemGroup, Item>` would be a good choice, but I am not clear how to properly wait on the `TransformManyBlock` dynamically created internally as the producer posts `ItemGroup` instances to it.

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: If you don't have to preserve the order of groups, a simple solution would be to create multiple transform blocks, each with a different DOP, and use `LinkTo`'s predicate to route each message to the correct block. In the simplest case you can create a fixed number of such blocks in advance. In a more complex scenario you could redirect any blocks that don't match the predicates to a block that checks the message's DOP, creates a new TransformBlock with the new DOP, links it to the others, and then posts the pending message to the new block.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you use this one-to-many-to-one pattern, and there is `BoundedCapacity` involved, you should be careful not to trigger [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31513 "Data loss during parallelization of BufferBlock") bug. The way to avoid it is to configure all the transform blocks with `EnsureOrdered = false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an inner `TransformBlock<Item, Item>` for each `ItemGroup` received. Below is a generalized solution with `TInput`, `TChild` and `TOutput` generic parameters. The `TInput` corresponds to a `ItemGroup`, the `TChild` corresponds to a `Item`, and the `TOutput` is also `Item` since you propagate the items without transforming them:

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput> CreateTransformManyDynamicBlock
    <TInput, TChild, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, IEnumerable<TChild>> childrenSelector,
    Func<TInput, int> degreeOfParallelismSelector,
    Func<TChild, TOutput> transformChild)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(childrenSelector);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(degreeOfParallelismSelector);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(transformChild);

    return new TransformManyBlock<TInput, TOutput>(async input =>
    {
        TransformBlock<TChild, TOutput> innerBlock = new(transformChild, new()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfParallelismSelector(input)
        });
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(input))
        {
            bool accepted = innerBlock.Post(child);
            if (!accepted) break; // The innerBlock has failed
        }
        innerBlock.Complete();

        // Propagate the results
        List<TOutput> results = new();
        while (await innerBlock.OutputAvailableAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            while (innerBlock.TryReceive(out TOutput result))
                results.Add(result);
        try { await innerBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); }
        catch when (innerBlock.Completion.IsCanceled) { throw; }
        catch { innerBlock.Completion.Wait(); } // Propagate AggregateException
        return results;
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
IPropagatorBlock<ItemGroup, Item> block =
    CreateTransformManyDynamicBlock<ItemGroup, Item, Item>(
        x => x.Items, x => x.MaxDegreeOfParallelism, x => x);
```

**Note:** The above code has not been tested.

---

**Update:** My original implementation ([revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74761037/1)) was based on the .NET 6 API [`ReceiveAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receiveallasync), and the `TransformManyBlock` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformmanyblock-2.-ctor#system-threading-tasks-dataflow-transformmanyblock-2-ctor(system-func((-0-system-collections-generic-iasyncenumerable((-1)))))) that takes a `Func<TInput,IAsyncEnumerable<TOutput>>` argument (.NET 7).
The problem was that the `ReceiveAllAsync` doesn't propagate the exception of the enumerated dataflow block,
so I switched to collecting and propagating manually the results, by filling a `List<TOutput>` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389273/for-a-tpl-dataflow-how-do-i-get-my-hands-on-all-the-output-produced-by-a-transf/62410007#62410007).

Comment: Thank you so much for the incredible detail, it was very enlightening. This was far simpler than what I thought was required. If I link the transform block created above to a buffer block with propagation, and post a bunch of groups to it, after I call complete() on the transform block the buffer is never signaled. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Ignore the completion issue, it was my mistake. Thank you again!

Comment: @Ritmo2k most likely you linked the blocks without the `PropagateCompletion` option. :-)

Comment: Btw I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/79535 "ReceiveAllAsync, ReadAllAsync and propagation of errors") on GitHub about the behavior of the `ReceiveAllAsync` API.